# Where is defined this service used to start a program?

Tags: 16.04, bash, services, startup-applications

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem. I am working on n **Ubuntu 16.04** system.

In this system I have a program that it is started from the command line in this way:

```
service wso2ei start
```

and stopped by:

```
service wso2ei stop
```

I think that somewhere it should be defined as a service or something like this. What exactly is this? And where is it defined these statment? (I think that is should be defined the association between the start command and the executable file that have to be executed)

Comment: So you want to know where `wso2ei` is defined ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yes I want to know what is actually started and where it is defined the configuration of this service

Answer (score 6):

Run `systemctl cat wso2ei` , it should tell you what file is used to define service and what is actually started.

It's worth mentioning that as of Ubuntu 15.04, Ubuntu has switched from Upstart to SystemD  system for managing services, which means what you run with `service` is likely going to be either Upstart service or sysvinit type of service converted to work with systemd, and the file location should be in `/run/systemd/generator.late/`.